# Deleting an object created using new keyword

Tags: c++

I have a class:

```
class temp
{
public:
    int id;
};
```

I will creating object for this class using `temp *obj = new temp();`, whenever we receive a command from user. command is in the form of string consisting of an id which we will attach to `obj->id`. also i am having an array which stores the objects of temp class:

```
temp* array[30];
```

I want to delete this object if I receive delete command from user. How can i delete it? Is it enough to do `delete obj` if i receive delete command from user?

Comment: We can't really tell you anything without knowing your architecture/design. `delete obj;` is a valid way to release resources allocated with `new`, but whether it's enough in your case, we really can't tell.

Comment: You should `delete` what you `new`, and `delete[]` what you `new[]`.

Comment: Be careful when you delete the object from the array, that you either a) notify all other references to this object in the array and/or b) reorder the array if the other code is somehow dependent on it. Do you really need a raw array? Maybe a vector will do. Also, you might want to check better memory management classes like unique_ptr and shared_ptr. However, as said before: without further knowledge of your code nobody can give you an exact answer (:

Comment: I would suggest you use a `std::vector` or `std::unique_ptr`s and then when you are done with the object you just erase it from the vector ans the `unique_ptr` will handle deleting the pointer.  RAII types can be very helpful for things like this.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on how you are accessing and using the object.  You should clean up after yourself by calling "delete" on memory that you allocate for objects with "new", but you only do that after you're completely done with the object.

You also have to clean up references to the object that you created.

For example, if you are dynamically allocating and deleting objects and keep using temp* array[30], you will need to make sure you never dereference a pointer in array[n] that points to an object that you have already deleted.

So it is usually not enough just to delete the object; you also have to remove all references to the object, or make sure they never get called.

Standard templates are more useful for this kind of memory management than is a primitive array.

Comment: The short version is "don't use new".  Use std::unique_ptr + std::make_unique or std::vector